# What different can I do in Computer Science other than ML and AI?

Tags: computer-science, career-path

I see everyone in my university learning about machine learning and artificial intelligence. I understand they might have a genuine interest in it but is it the only subject that computer science is heading towards?

I have a deep interest in low-level computer science and have done projects in which I have designed compilers, assemblers and an RTOS running on microcontrollers.

Comment: The topics that you mentioned are common in "technical computer science" or "computer engineering" courses of study, which are sometimes separate from the normal CS courses. So, you may just be looking at the course catalogue that is not the right one for your personal interests.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the close votes nor the down votes on answers. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Buffy "Explain to me the subfields of computer science" is not an on-topic question here, and I'm not sure how it could be considered on-topic, but computer science and math questions usually get a pass and get answered here even when very off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, any of the upper level courses in CS teach things that can still be extended, some more than others. But database and language design, for example aren't at the end of their lifetimes. Higher level abstractions are always open to research (and development). Security is still a major issue.

Machine Learning and what goes by the name of Artificial Intelligence are both pretty hot right now, so you hear a lot about them. (I'm an AI skeptic who avoids the hype). And any hot field will cool over time. If you are an undergraduate with, say, a decade before you can start a research career, the world might look quite a lot different then than it does now. Don't get too specialized too early. Learn a lot of things so that you can be flexible when it comes time to make serious choices.

Answer (score 1):

CS is an enormous subject. Even if you restrict to just the software side it is enormous.

Grab a course catalog from a university with a CS department. Treat it as an "all you can learn" buffet. Pick something that grabs your attention. You will be more likely to excel and enjoy your time there if you find it interesting. Take a couple classes in it and see if it really is for you. But take classes in a bunch of things.

You can find course catalogs on line for many universities. Google for them, starting with the universities you are most interested in attending, maybe the closest one to your home.